# Reading CLOB by OleDb problems

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I am getting an error message mentioning that data type not supported. I think because i am trying to read a CLOB file. Is there anyways can solve it, belwo is the code

```
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
        OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: try using ODP.NET, CLOB is not supported by OleDb

Comment: thanks, i searchign for it now. Can i use ODP.Net only for 1 form but rest use Oledb as i done some with oledb already

Comment: Yes, you can do it,  but it is not recommended.

Comment: sor sir, what sir reccoment?

Comment: Use the same connector for all operations, unless you have multiple and different data sources.

Comment: sir, i really appreciate if sir able to help me as i try ind i am not ure which to downlaod, i am using 32-bit, and in my sqlplus stated using Oracle Database Entrerprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0. I wonloaded but can't connect to visual studio states TNS timeout. Is there a way to solve it. I wonload was ODT

Comment: Always use 32-bit for develop (Visual studio = 32 bit)  . Please, add some relevant code about your connection and conn str or TNS. Check this as basic guideline https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/connecting.htm